# class substitution in php

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor

Is there any way to make it work? See example :

```
class car {
        function __construct($type){
                switch ($type) {
                        case 'big' : return new big_car();
                        case 'small' : return new small_car();
                }
        }
        function whatisit () {
                echo "this is car ;( \n";
        }
}

class big_car extends car {
        function __construct(){}
        function whatisit () {
                echo "this is big car ;) \n";
        }
}

class small_car extends car {
        function __construct(){}
        function whatisit () {
                echo "this is small car ;) \n";
        }
}
```

so the goal is to use it this way:

```
$mycar = new car('big');
$mycar->whatisit(); // i want it to say that it's big
```

I guess very much that its bad way and it cannot work this way but maybe there is a trick?

PS:: I know I can use special static method for that but...

Comment: Constructors can't return values in PHP; you'll need another method.

Comment: @kitty upvoted for your nick+avatar.

Comment: You need to add a "car" interface and a "car" factory - trying to do them both together is ugly and hard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a car factory to create new cars; this is not JavaScript :)

```
class car_factory 
{
    function create_car($type = null) 
    {
        switch ($type) {
             case 'big':
                 return new big_car();

             case 'small':
                 return new small_car();

             case null:
                 return new car();
        }
        throw new InvalidArgumentException($type);
    }
}

$factory = new car_factory;
$small_car = $factory->create_car('small');
$std_car = $factory->create_car();
```

Of course, you should remove the `__construct` function from your original code.

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676544/class-substitution-in-php/16676579?noredirect=1#comment24004425_16676579) in the comments you could completely generalize this by using dynamic classes, assuming class extensions have the same constructor and class naming is consistent:

```
class car_factory
{
    function create_car($type = null)
    {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            return new car();
        }

        $class = "{$type}_car";
        if (class_exists($class)) {
            $obj = new $class();

            if ($obj instanceof car) {
                return $obj;
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException($type);
    }
}
```

Personally I have no preferences either way; if extensibility is a key factor, go for it, otherwise stick with a simple `switch`.

Comment: To behave the way he wanted I believe it should `return new car();` when the argument is not `big` or `small`, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: This example is not very extensible. If you add other types, you'll need to change class implementation. You could try to do the instanciation based on the parameter `$type`: `$class = "{$type}_car"; return new $class()`. In this case, all you'll have to do is maintain the naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

> [...]you could completely generalize this by using dynamic classes, assuming class extensions have the same constructor and class naming is consistent

You can add even more flexibility using Reflection:

```
class car_factory
{
    function create_car($class = null, $constructorArgs = array())
    {
        if (is_null($class)) {
            return new car();
        }

        try {
           $refl = new ReflectionClass($class);
           if (!$refl->isSubclassOf('car') {
               throw new DomainException("Type: {$class} is not a car type");
           }
           return $refl->newIntanceArgs($constructorArgs);
        } catch(ReflectionException $e) {
           throw new DomainException("Invalid car type: {$class}");
        }
    }
}
```

Now use:

```
$factory = new car_factory();
$car1 = $factory->create_car('big_car');
$car2 = $factory->create_car('small_car');
$car3 = $factory->create_car('fancy_car_name_with_constructor_args', array("I'm fancy!"));
```

Comment: Also, if you want to just pass objects you can skip the relfection and use `type-hinting`: `function __construct(\Car $car) { $this->car = $car; }`

Comment: In this case you'd have to instantiate an object and pass it to the factory, so, what is the factory for?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't talking about this specific case - just posting that for anyone that might be reading over this answer. It's actually DI design instead of a factory pattern which seems to be better for testing anyway.

Comment: Why do you say that DI Design is better than Factory Method for testing?

Comment: Because most factories have more connections to the objects they are creating that containers which only define a type of object they are *expecting*.